# Simple form and Twitter Bootstrap DateTime Picker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, twitter

I am making a scheduling web page and for the input date and time I am using Simple Form and Twitter BootStrap DateTime Picker. I am using [this gem 'datetimepicker-rails'](https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails). It is working.

My problem is that the time formats in the dropdown are in 24hr format instead of the 12 hour format. Instead of 1pm it is using 13.

I have tried to set the format to 12 hours with not luck

```
   $('.time_picker').datetimepicker({
      pick12HourFormat: true
   })
```

The error I am receiving in the console is `option pick12HourFormat is not recognized!`

My form

```
= simple_form_for [@user, @workday], url: user_workdays_path do |f|
  = f.input :start_date, label: 'Start Date (required)', :as => :date_picker
  = f.input :start_time, label: 'Start Time (required)', :as => :time_picker

  = f.input :end_date, label: 'End Date (required)', :as => :date_picker
  = f.input :end_time, label: 'End Time (required)', :as => :time_picker
  = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-default'
```

Additionally I have tried configuring the `en.yml` file with no luck.

Comment: Try : ´use24hours: false´

Comment: No luck with `use24hours:false`

Comment: I think you should set the options in the config/locale file. That's what the documentation says, and how it's done in the demo: https://github.com/zpaulovics/dateTimeDemo/tree/master/config/locales. Did you try this?

Comment: I saw that in the docs as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on one of my applications. The 'pick12HourFormat' looks fine with your code.

Check your JS assets to make sure they are in the correct order as stated in the documentation:

```
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require pickers
```

Also check to see if you are using the correct class:

```
$('.time_picker')

# Compared to
$('.time-picker')
```